# GAE - get() entity by property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How would I go about getting a Datastore entity based on an entity of the property? Do I have to go through a multi-step filter() get() process? Or can I accomplish this through a 1 piece get()?

For example let's say I have the Datastore model Channel:

```
class Channel(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
```

Now if I want to delete a channel based on it's name, how could I do something like:

```
name = "ch1"
channel = Channel.get("name = " name)
channel.delete()
```

This get statement doesn't work. What's the actually method to accomplish this by? Thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can retrieve an entity according to a property

```
q = db.Query(Channel)
q.filter("name =", name)
entities = q.fetch(100) # The number of entities you want to be returned
if entries:    
    db.delete(entries)
```

Comment: Makes sense. But there's not a return first entity version like get() does? You have to return an iterable even if it just has 1 entity?

Comment: Query, returns an iterable, you have to use get_by_id() or [get_by_key_name()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_get_by_key_name). If you are sure that the name is going to be unique for each channel, then you can assign it as a key_name of the entity.

Comment: @golmschenk yes you can use get() too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this, you're better off changing your design slightly. If you're fetching channels by name, then it would be far easier (and faster and cheaper) to use the name of the channel as the key name instead.

Just pass the `key_name` parameter when creating the entity (examples borrowed from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key)):

```
employee = Employee(key_name='asalieri',
                first_name='Antonio',
                last_name='Salieri')
```

And fetch it by with

```
k = Key.from_path('Employee', 'asalieri')
```

Once you have the key, all other operations can proceed as usual.

Answer (score 0):

If the name field is uniquely identify an entity, better to use it as key as mentioned by Sudhir. However, if there are multiple entities having same name, you'll need to fetch them first

```
all = Channel.all(keys_only=True).fetch(1000) # only need key to delete
db.delete(all)
```

one line version

```
db.delete(Channel.all(keys_only=True).fetch(1000))
```